# Execute async callback from synchronous code immediately

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7, threadpoolexecutor

**Problem**

I have a library which currently has no async support and needs to  be called from async code. The async code calls into the library through a handler (`handler` function in the code below). While the handler executed, the library periodically calls a callback (`callback_wrapper`) to report progress.

The synchronous handler is executed in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in order for the main event loop to be able to process further events while the handler is running.

What happens is that the synchronous callback is executed immediately, but the async callback is only executed after the main handler has executed. The desired result is the async callbacks to be executed immediately.

I guess the event loop is blocked at the `run_in_executor` call, but I am not sure how to resolve this.

**Code**

```py
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def handler():
    print('handler started')
    callback_wrapper()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('handler stopped')


async def callback():
    print('callback')


def callback_wrapper():
    print('callback wrapper started')
    asyncio.ensure_future(callback(), loop=loop)
    print('callback wrapper stopped')


async def main():
    handler()


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    async def thread_handler():
        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, handler)


    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Output**

```
handler started
callback wrapper started
callback wrapper stopped
handler stopped
callback
```

**Desired Output**

```
handler started
callback wrapper started
callback
callback wrapper stopped
handler stopped
```

Comment: This won't work. Your `main()` is a coroutine in name only - it doesn't await anything, and it calls a blocking function. You should probably use two threads, one that runs the asyncio event loop, and the other that runs the blocking code. Then you can use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit tasks to the event loop and block (your thread) until they finish.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, your input helped me get on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @user4815162342's input, I came up the the following solution:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def handler():
    print('handler started')
    callback_wrapper()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('handler stopped')


async def callback():
    print('callback')


def callback_wrapper():
    print('callback wrapper started')
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(callback(), loop).result()
    print('callback wrapper stopped')


async def main():
    await thread_handler()


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    async def thread_handler():
        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, handler)


    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

which produces the desired result:

```
handler started
callback wrapper started
callback
callback wrapper stopped
handler stopped
```

Comment: I think you also need a call to `.result()` when you invoke `run_coroutine_threadsafe`. (It returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object which provides a blocking `result()` method.) Also, your `thread_handler` coroutine does not appear to be used anywhere.

Comment: @user4815162342 you are correct, I have updated the code above

Comment: Looks good, I believe that should work robustly. You can even start multiple coroutines and await them _en masse_ using [`concurrent.futures.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) and so on.